# Windows automation with Applescript and WINE

Tags: automation, applescript, ui-automation, wine

Can I automate a windows application running on Wine with Applescript?
If not, is there another way to script a windows app on Wine OSX?

Comment: wow this sounds very kludgy way of doing something in windows why not use vb or somehting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not tried it with Wine but with Parallels I just do GUI scripting and send keystrokes directly to the application.  Here's a blog post I wrote on it.  (Although I use Python + Appscript for scripting primarily)

http://www.libertypages.com/clarktech/?p=1496

Note I send each character separately in that script.  You can actually send full strings.  I just like it abstracted out so I can add a delay if necessary.  So I have a function for sending strings.

If you're not familiar with GUI Scripting I'd look at the following tutorial:

http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/uiscripting/index.html